# Redirect after submit to next page

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to link two php pages having questions. Once a form is submitted it checks on database to store the value and then it must redirect to next page.
But I'm stuck here at header() function. It's not redirecting to next page. Where am I doing it wrong?

```
    $q1= "SELECT * FROM user_lang WHERE lang='$lang' AND q_id='1'";
$r1=mysqli_query($connection, $q1) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
$row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r1);

$q2="SELECT * FROM user_test WHERE mid='$username'";
$r2=mysqli_query($connection, $q2) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
$row2=mysqli_fetch_row($r2);
echo '<div class="wrapper" style="padding-top:5%;">';
echo '<div class="login-page">
<h2 align="center">'.$lang.' Module 1</h2>';
if(isset($_POST['answer']))
{
    $answer=$_POST['answer'];
    if(mysqli_num_rows($r2)>0)
    {
$loadquery2="UPDATE user_test SET q1='$answer' WHERE mid='$username'";
$loadres2=mysqli_query($connection,$loadquery2) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
        header('Location: "/vtest/q2.php"');
    }
    else
    {
        $loadquery2="INSERT INTO user_test(mid,q1) VALUES ('$username','$answer')";
        $loadres2=mysqli_query($connection,$loadquery2) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
        header('Location: "/vtest/q2.php"');
    }
}
else
{
echo "<form method='POST'>";
echo $row1['quest'];
echo '<br><input type="radio" name="answer" value="a" checked>'.$row1['o1'].'<br>';
echo '<input type="radio" name="answer" value="b" >'.$row1['o2'].'<br>';
echo '<input type="radio" name="answer" value="c" >'.$row1['o3'].'<br>';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit">';
echo"</form>";
}
echo '</div></div></body></html>';
?>
```

BTW this file is named q1.php & when I submit the form the url doesn't change. I think it means its not a fault on page q2.php but on q1.php itself.

Comment: header code will not run after echo or any html tag. you need to move your condition at top

Comment: So isn't there any method apart from closing the php?

Comment: you can use javascript redirect method.. `echo '<script>window.location.href="your path"</script>';`

Comment: Yeah now trying with javascript! Well its working

Comment: you can use your if else condition at top

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
 header('Location: "/vtest/q2.php"');
```

with

```
 header("Location: /vtest/q2.php");
 exit;
```

**UPDATE**

1) there should not be any output (i.e. echo.. or HTML codes) before the header(.......); command.

2) there should not be a white-space(or newline) before `<?php and after ?>` tags.

3) GOLDER RULE! - the file (and also, if you include other files) have **UTF8** without BOM encoding (and not just UTF-8). That is problem in many cases (because UTF8 encoded file has something special character in the start of file output)!!!!!!!!!!!

4) Turn on error reporting. And tell the error.

5) If redirecting, then after header(...); you must use exit;

6) always use 301 or 302 in reference:

```
  header("location: http://example.com",  true,  301 );  exit;
```

7) If none of above helps, use JAVSCRIPT redirection(not recommended By Google), but it may be the last chance...:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.top.location='http://example.com/';</script>"; exit;
```

Comment: have u check it tht your update or insert query working ?